# Missing stereo channel in iOS5

Tags: ios5, core-audio, audiounit

Just updated to iOS5 and noticed that the app we are working on has lost its audio output in the right channel. Being unsure with our own implementation of the audio unit component, I tried running the MixerHost sample from Apple and apparently the right channel is missing too.

I believe this has something to do with the recent changes to CoreAudio in iOS5 (maybe an additional unit or attribute needed?). Hopefully someone can point out what that is. Thanks for the help.